# Overflow cause scroll when it it have an absolute element

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .wrap {
        overflow-x: auto;
      }

      .content {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 800px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        background-color: red;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="absolute"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have an page like above.

For some reason, I set min-width for `.content`, so I `set overflow-x: auto;` for `.wrap`.

In `.content`, I have an `absolute element`.

Result:

[image]

As you see, one `scroll bar` appear.

If i remove `overflow-x: auto;` in `.wrap`:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .wrap {
      }

      .content {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 800px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        background-color: red;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="absolute"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`overflow-x: auto;` cause scroll when child have an `absolute element`. But I til need `overflow-x: auto;` for scrollable of content when browser screen is small.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

The vertical scrollbar appears because, as per [the Overflow CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#ref-for-valdef-overflow-visible%E2%91%A0):

> The `visible`/`clip` values of `overflow` compute to `auto`/`hidden` (respectively) if one of `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` is neither `visible` nor `clip`.

Since `overflow-x` is set to `auto` and we have the default initial `overflow-y` value of `visible`, the `visible` value computes to `auto`, thus the vertical scrollbar.

Thus, to remove the vertical scrollbar, we can set the `overflow-y` value to `hidden`:

```css
.wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Edit

To have the `absolute` element be able display fully, one could consider increasing the height of `wrap` to `300px`:

```css
.wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to hidden the `.absolute`. I want the the `.absolute` fill out like normal (dont have `overflow-x: auto`)

Comment: Added additional solution